# Should the profiles with same email be automatically merged?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, merge-accounts

The full order of event related to this problem was:

1. I [asked a question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5595/5425) on http://vi.stackexchange.com (not signed up)
2. Decided to respond to one of the comment
   2a. System said that for the feedback but you need to be signed up.... etc etc
   2b. I had to sign up
3. I commented.

The problem:

1. When I asked the question. The user ID assigned to me was [`2024`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/5424/santosh-kumar) (vi.SE)
2. When system forced me to sign up, user ID assigned to me was another [`2025`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/5425/santosh-kumar).
3. Now I am not able to accept the answer to my own question.

---

**Fix?**: Maybe StackExchange engine should merge profiles with same email ID automatically?

---

This question might seem duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104000/181377) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269340/181377) question, but note that I'm not looking for support, I'm suggesting an upgrade.

Comment: Well, as far as I talk about the manual merge as describe on this [Meta FAQ page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/181377), my profiles haven't been merged yet. Even after the verification process. I still can't accept answer for my question.

Comment: As far as I know, SE *does* merge profiles (even if this is sometimes undesired), so this would appear to be a support request, or perhaps a recently-introduced bug.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few checks and balances in the automatic account merge system, mostly to avoid accidental merges and to ensure there is some oversight when certain conditions occur.

For example, if one of the identified accounts is for a high rep user on one of the sites, a CM (or developer) needs to approve the merge.

This is what happened here - the merge was sitting in a queue till I approved it.

Comment: _is for a high rep user_ can you add the cut off rep?