# What happened to my Profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, login, user-accounts

I wanted to Sign In as I do regularly, but when I clicked Sign In, I first saw a page about some problems that had appeared before (because of which I had been logged out). I decided to Sign In with Google Account this time. So I clicked this button and voila - now I am my wife.

I didn't choose my Google account, it seems that it had synced with the one that was active at that moment (which was my wife's account, but not sure... may be not). Now, my old link to my profile says it doesn't exist. https://stackoverflow.com/users/7376567/gprost

But here is a new hybrid page (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6250385/elena-teresa?tab=profile) of my achievements and my wife's avatar. However, there are also some strange things: I don't have all the badges I had, and I think the reputation has some glitches too.

When I Log Out and Sign In with my email + password the result is the same. But here in Meta, I am still me, I also have link to my Stack Overflow profile in Meta Profile page (https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/349545/gprost?tab=profile) but it leads to my new hybrid page, and it also doesn't match with the badges I had.

Comment: Congrats! Your profiles have been merged. On a serious note... your profiles have been merged, automatically. I doubt this can be reverted. Next time make sure to use different browsers or at least different user profiles to browse each account.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I thought profiles were not merged automatically, precisely because it has major consequences and is hard to undo?

Comment: @S.L.Barth see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270042/152859)

Comment: Merges can be undone, don't worry. I'll ping someone more familiar with it, well sort this out.

Comment: @Sha We can unmerge when the accounts are verifiably not the same person. We don't unmerge when they are the same person and they just still wanted to have two accounts, because we don't officially support running multiple accounts.

Answer (score 9):

Alright, I clicked this scary button:

[image]

and … *drummroll* ...

```
Network Account Unmerge - splitting previous account: 9970237 from master account: 8317642
   Queuing unmerge for site 1 (Stack Overflow)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 2 (Server Fault)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 3 (Super User)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 4 (Meta Stack Exchange)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 69 (Mathematics Stack Exchange)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 89 (Ask Ubuntu)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 97 (English Language & Usage Stack Exchange)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 102 (User Experience Stack Exchange)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 106 (Unix & Linux Stack Exchange)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 118 (Ask Different)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 131 (Software Engineering Stack Exchange)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 155 (Stack Exchange)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 162 (Information Security Stack Exchange)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 196 (Code Review Stack Exchange)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 419 (Computer Science Stack Exchange)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 423 (The Workplace Stack Exchange)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 599 (Vi and Vim Stack Exchange)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 609 (Stack Overflow на русском)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 619 (Open Source Stack Exchange)...done.
   Queuing unmerge for site 642 (Ethereum Stack Exchange)...done.
Moved 2 AccountCredential entries to Account.Id=11968295
Moved 4 AccountHistory entries to Account.Id=11968295
No AccountHistory (Moderator) entries to unmerge
No BanHistory entries to unmerge
Moved 47 AccountLoginHistory entries to Account.Id=11968295
Moved 210 Inboxes entries to Account.Id=11968295
Moved 44 Achievements entries to Account.Id=11968295
Moved 26 AccountSessions entries to Account.Id=11968295
Unmerging VerifiedEmail...
   Master verified Email matches, no unmerge to perform
No Applications entries to unmerge
Moved 1 Application History entries to Account.Id=11968295
No Auth Codes entries to unmerge
Moved 1 Access Tokens entries to Account.Id=11968295
ProvidenceOptOut preferences unmerged
Network account merge complete.

Recorded unmerge history...done.
```

… congratulations, you are no longer your wife!

(You did get a new user id though.)

Comment: Thx for that! But still, I have 0 tags score now, although I have 99 answers. Also not all of my badges restored. Can this be fixed? And is there a possibility to restore my Developer page (it is the least important).

Btw, wouldn't be better if you would check email matches for Google Account and StackOverflow before merge?

Comment: Sorry. It shows that there is an error in the image. It seems imgur is blocked in my region. It worked till few minutes ago. Please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301952/se-icon-in-top-bar-disappears-when-hovering#comment981950_301952) comment.

Comment: @balpha imgur seems broken for some again, I also don't see the image, I only get an Error 503.

Comment: reported on MSO as well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357690/imgur-returning-503-service-unavailable

Comment: @GProst A bunch of things that will automatically be recalculated anyway aren't restored by an unmerge, that includes the tag stats and certain badges. They should re-appear within 24 hours.

Comment: @balpha, thank you, will wait then.

Comment: @balpha looks like high rep users, why auto merge has been triggered in the first place?

Comment: @Sha It wasn't auto-merged, it was approved from queue because they appeared to be the same person based on the information that was shown.

Comment: @balpha, I have one issue with 'job alerts'. I would like to stop it, but it looks like I can't do this: when I go to the unsubscribe link it says that I have wrong account. Currently I don't have any job alerts, but messages keep coming because I had it in account before merge.

Comment: @GProst I'll ping someone about this.

Comment: @GProst You should now be unsubscribed from all job alerts (I found an active job alert and disabled it). If for some reason you receive more, feel free to ping us through the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) (select "other").