# SE icon in top bar disappears when hovering

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

The SE icon on the left hand side of the top bar disappears when you hover over it on [Unix and Linux](http://linux.stackexchange.com):

Idle (hard to read and almost invisible):

[image: top bar SE icon on U&L]

Hover:

[image: top bar SE icon when hovered]

I'm not sure if any of the current icon behaviors are intentional. Are we *supposed* to see a big square appear around the element when we hover? Is it really by design? And I really don't know if any of the colors are intentional since I have a lot of trouble reading the colored text on a black background on all of the various sites I tested. But I'm pretty sure that having it disappear, at least, is a bug.

<sub>This may or may not be the same issue as [Odd red SE logo on New top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301940/203101)</sub>.

Comment: Imgur seems to be acting up. Assuming they fix it, the images should become visible. If not, just visit [unix.se].

Comment: The links are not working. It seems imgur *is unable to handle this request.* I think the logo is a deep blue so when a mouse hovers above it it appears to sink in the background. See my [recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301940/odd-red-se-logo-on-new-top-bar) on meta, I think your question is strongly related.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yeah, I asked Paweł if this is the same issue. It wasn't clear to me from your question and his answer which part of the behavior was by design and which a bug.

Comment: Yeah. It appears like it's disappearing. I say a bad choice of colours in case of Unix & Linux.

Comment: Doesn't quite disappear, but the color and hover colors make it very difficult to make out when hovering. We are looking into why the logo is taking the site link color (reported elsewhere), which is the cause of this issue.

Comment: @Oded cool, I wasn't sure if I should close this as a dupe of the other or not. But note that for my eyes and on my screen it does disappear if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yeah, appreciate that, can easily depend on how color calibrated a monitor is (and what gamut it can display)... and of course different eyes will see things differently. Was not attempting to discredit/disregard your report :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301940/odd-red-se-logo-on-new-top-bar - is marked as fixed, so probably just need to deploy network-wide.

Comment: @terdon - should be fixed now. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Oded Yay! Looks great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks for reporting. Logo color was an issue across whole network. It should now be fixed.